# WIX is property set

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Using the commandline I can execute an 'msi' file like this:

```
myProgramm.msi myProperty="abc"
```

In my wxs file I want to set myProperty (for example to 'xyz') only if it is not defined.

Comment: What is you question? What have you tried so far? Which tools are you using to create the MSI package?

Comment: i am working with visual studio 2012 and use the wix from that.

Comment: "myProperty" isn't a public property and cannot be passed at the command line.

Comment: what i had tryed
<?ifndef P.SqlServer ?>
   <Property Id="P.IP"
             Value="localhost" />      
<?endif?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You should use this:

```
<SetProperty Id="P.IP" 
             After="AppSearch" 
             Sequence="first" 
             Value="SomeValue">NOT P.IP</SetProperty>
```

I changed Sequence to 'First' - it will execute only once: either during InstallUISEquence (if it executes) or during InstallExecuteSequence (otherwise - silent mode). But maybe you really need setting property in both sequences - you should decide. If you want to specify properties from command-line, you can consider using silent mode run:

```
msiexec  /i setup.msi /qn /lv*x install.log P.PASSWORD="xxx" P.IP="192.168.1.1"
```

or basic UI mode:

```
msiexec  /i setup.msi /qb /lv*x install.log P.PASSWORD="xxx" P.IP="192.168.1.1"
```

Also I would recommend reading Rob Menching's article on Remember property pattern - it relates to registry search setting of a property when it is passed from command-line: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern.

Comment: First vs Both doesn't matter because the condition will evaluate to false on the second run.  Downvoting since you basically stole and reposted my answer.

Comment: Sorry - my answer was to user1833301 second post since he incorrectly understood you. Probably comment was more appropriate. As for both - I don't agree - in case custom action is scheduled earlier than dialog with that property is shown, you can change property later from UI (For example, I don't really need the value somebody provided in command-line and I erase it in UI dialog). In this case your custom action will be executed second time once more overwriting the empty value. And your UI-provided value, which should have the top priority gets ignored.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [SetProperty](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) element.  The inner text of the element is a condition that must evaluate to true for the SetProperty to occur.

Assuming you are properly using a Secure Custom Public Property,  the code would look like:

```
<SetProperty Id="MYPROPERTY" After="AppSearch" Sequence="both" Value="SomeValue">Not MYPROPERTY</SetProperty>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the need to use custom actions. If you create PUBLIC property with value and add it SecureCustomProperties list, then it will have value provided, unless you override it with command line. That is:

```
<Property Id='P.IP' Value="Localhost" Secure='yes'>
```

Then, if you just run installer, you'll end up with P.IP=Localhost, and if you launch msi with providing value for it, that value will be stored until you uninstall your package, i.e.:

```
msiexec /i <YouPackage.Msi> P.IP=192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Ya, probably true.  I get so much flack around here though when I dig too deep into what the poster really needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
msiexec  /i setup.msi /lv*x install.log P.PASSWORD="xxx" P.IP="192.168.1.1"
```

so when i want to set the P.IP only if the user had not set it in the command line i could use this?:

```
<SetProperty Id="P.IP" 
             After="AppSearch" 
             Sequence="both" 
             Value="SomeValue">localhost</SetProperty>
```